# Can't access method from the model class in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am trying to use method from the model class but its throwing error like

> ERROR TypeError: act.sayHi is not a function

Here is my code

> Model Class myModelClass.ts

```
    export interface IMymodel {
        name: string;
        address: string;
        age: number;
    }

    export class Mymodel implements IMymodel {
        name: string;
        address: string;
        age: number 

        constructor() {}

        sayHi(name): string {
            console.log('Hiii' + name);
            return 'Hiii'+name;
        }

    }
```

> Component MyComponent.ts

```
import { IMymodel, Mymodel } from '../model/myModelClass.ts';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'myComponent.html'
})
export class MyComponent {

    ...

    prepareData(data: Array<IMymodel>): Array<IMymodel> {

         data.map((act: Mymodel) => {
             act.sayHi(act.name);
         });

         return data;
    } 

}
```

Comment: One thing I can immediately see is that your `sayHi` method should be returning a string, but you are not doing it. Do you not get a compile error from that?

Comment: ya, return is there, I will update the code .. sorry

Comment: Please, include all relevant code and provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . There's no evidence that act is an instance of Mymodel class. Considering that the error is there you can be sure that it isn't.

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vnykSJ/40j9wjsv/) is the fiddle which reproduces the issue, code is bit different in the fiddle but the scenario and what I was trying to achieve is same

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `sayHi` method signature into the interface too as you access your objects via interface type and that type lacks a method with name `sayHi`.

```
export interface IMymodel {
    name: string;
    address: string;
    age: number;
    sayHi(name): string
}
```

and method call

```
prepareData(data: Array<IMymodel>): Array<IMymodel> {

     data.map((act: IMymodel) => {
         act.sayHi(act.name);
     });

     return data;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but still no luck, I am still getting the same error